# AutoDesk Forge Design Automation API Quota

Tags: autodesk-designautomation

Do [these quotas](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v2/overview/quotas/) only apply to trial accounts?

When I exceed the 5 requests per minute limitation, the error message says:

```
You reached Quota limit. Your total free Quota is 5 requests per minute. Please try again soon.
```

Which sounds specific to trial accounts, but the documentation linked to above does not specify.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This applies to all accounts. We can override this (any other documented limit) for specific clients if necessary.

Comment: Thank you Albert for the response to James. Cheers!